# How to change the font of UINavigation Controller Header.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I wanted to know how can we change the font size of the title of a view while using UINavigationController.., 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    self.title = @"";
    UILabel *myNavigationTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, self.view.frame.size.width, 33)];
    myNavigationTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myNavigationTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myNavigationTitleLabel.text = @"my Custom title";
    myNavigationTitleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    myNavigationTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:myNavigationTitleLabel];
    [myNavigationTitleLabel release];
```

Note that if you have landscape interface orientation you need to set new frame for the myNavigationTitleLabel.

Comment: But.., doing this..., will however create a new Label of our own font size but, When we go back to the previous screen or navigate to the next screen.., The Label is still present in the header...

Comment: Just remove the label [myNavigationTitleLabel removeFromSuperView] in view will disappear delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly change it. Create a custom `UILabel`, or any other view, with the style you want and assign it as `self.navigationItem.titleView`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

change the font and title...

> +(void) setNavigationTitle:(NSString *) title
>   ForNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *) navigationItem {
>         UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
>   0.0f, 200.0f, 44.0f)];
>
> ```
> UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc]
> ```
>
> initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 6.0f, 200.0f,30.0f)];
>
> ```
> [titleLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BellCent NamNum BT"
> ```
>
> size:24.0]];
>
> ```
> [titleLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
> [titleLbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
>
> [titleLbl setTextColor:UIColorFromRedGreenBlue(35,134,192)];
> [titleLbl setShadowColor:UIColorFromRedGreenBlue(186,186,186)];
> [titleLbl setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
>
> [titleLbl setText:title];
>
>   [view addSubview:titleLbl];
>
> [navigationItem setTitleView:view];
> [titleLbl release];
>
>  }
> ```